# Jquery datatable custom search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

using data table I want to write a search only for my span tag text  inside column 1

```
 <td> 
 <span class="name">Hyderabad Days</span>
 sometext
 </td>


var dTable = $("#dashboard-table").DataTable({
"aoColumnDefs": [{
    "iDataSort": 0,
    "aTargets": [0]
}],
"bLengthChange": false,
"ordering": false,
})



$("#data_table_filter").keyup(function(){
   dTable.columns(1).search($(this).val()).draw()

});
```

Comment: will u please elaborate?

Comment: @HirenModi: well I have a custom search box outside the data table, so am performing search operation on the data table, now in my table first column has span and some other data i want to search only the span